# how to add jaxws:endpoint programmatically to a soap web-service plugin app , using loadBus() or adding config-location at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I am migrating from axis to cxf for my web-service. I have a plugin module for which i have hardcoded endpoint in servicesbeans.xml :

```
....other endpoints....

<jaxws:endpoint id="CardHandlerPortImpl"
                endpointName="CardHandlerPort"
                implementor="com.smarttrust.jam.dpadmin.request.CardHandler"
                address="/CardHandlerService">
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

servicebeans.xml is added as below in web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ProvisioningApiCXFServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>config-location</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/iservicesbeans.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This hardcoded endpoint works fine but for my case as i have to install a plugin , i want this endpoint to be added dynamically when application boots up . There can be two approaches for this :

1. create a config xml like iservicebeans_2.xml and add that programmatically .
2. Using the method listed here [using bus](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html)

for the first approach , primary question was does it support multiple config locations ? So i tried with comma/space separated as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344264/add-multiple-endpoint-service-classes-using-apache-cxf) (though different Servlet). But adding hardcoded paths didn't work let alone be the programmatic approach. If this is possible then any example/ref will help.

Using the second approach this [thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o4m3kscjt336hbscjpsyc14cthsgqb4d) was close , but i cannot instantiate CXFServlet myself as i am not spinning my own server , rather the webservice app is deployed in tomcat. So i might need a ref of CXFServlet in code to call *Bus bus = servlet.getBus();* to get bus. As i am not using Spring @Autowired will not give CXFServlet's instance . Here as well any example or reference will help .

I saw this piece of code inside CXFServlet class which can be used to set multiple locations as the name suggests , so it might be taking space separated config-locations . But couldn't find any example . Sorry for long post . TIA

> ctx2.setConfigLocations(new String[]{location});